# Delete filled in details after restart

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to let a person fill in some details and return an overview of the details. There is an option to restart the conversation (look at code) but when the conversation is restarted and the person fill in some new details, it will show the old details of the first filled in details.

How can i fix this problem ?

```
bot.dialog('overview', function (session, options) {
if (session.message && session.message.value) {
    if(session.message.value.actions == "Accept"){

    }
    return;
}
var overview_msg = require('./cards/overview.json');
var date = new Date();
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[0].items[1].columns[1].items[0].text = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[0].items[1].columns[1].items[0].text.replace(/{{name}}/,nameGuest)
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[0].items[1].columns[1].items[1].text = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[0].items[1].columns[1].items[1].text.replace(/{{date}}/,date.toDateString() +' ' + date.toLocaleTimeString());
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[0].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[0].value.replace(/{{email}}/, mailGuest);
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[1].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[1].value.replace(/{{phone}}/, phoneGuest);
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[2].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[2].value.replace(/{{extra}}/, numberPeople);

overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value.replace(/{{lunch}}/, lunchGuest);
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value.replace(/{{allergy}}/, lunchAllergyGuest);
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[3].value.replace(/{{vegan}}/, lunchVegan);
session.send(overview_msg);

bot.dialog('restart', function (session) {
    session.beginDialog('overview');
}).triggerAction({matches: /restart|quit/i});
```

Comment: How are nameGuest, mailGuest, phoneGuest, etc. populated?

Comment: Those are local variables containing an empty string. Because i need to reuse those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i managed to get it done.
Instead of replacing the value in the json i referred to the variable.

example:

```
overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[0‌​].value = VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may relate to how you define variables `nameGuest, mailGuest, phoneGuest, etc` which are not shown in your code snippet.

For getting values from `Input.Text` of `adaptive-card`, you can try the following code snippet:

```
bot.dialog('form', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        let card = require('./card.json');
        if (session.message && session.message.value) {
            next(session.message.value)
        } else {
            var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                .addAttachment(card);
            session.send(msg);
        }

    },
    (session, results) => {
        // Get the User input data here
        session.send(JSON.stringify(results));

    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: ['form', 'Action.Submit']
})
```

Comment: Those are local variables containing an empty string. Because i also need the variables in my code. But why does the adaptive card shows me the old values? I reuse the required card, so normal this one is empty? Isn't it ?

Comment: I doubt that these sentence like `overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[0].value = overview_msg.attachments[0].content.body[1].items[1].facts[0].value.replace(/{{email}}/, mailGuest);
` will affect the card json string, and variables like `mailGuest` will be assigned some value in some place. I suggest you can set a break point before `session.send(msg)` to check the exact value of cord.